# vi/vim/view /etc/alternatives loop

Tags: gnome, vim, symbolic-link, etc

I wanted to understand the difference between the executables `vi` and `vim`. `which` has led me to `/usr/bin/`, and there I've found the following symlinks:

```
/usr/bin/vi -> /etc/alternatives/vi
/usr/bin/vim -> /etc/alternatives/vim
```

Going to `/etc/alternatives/`, I saw that these names link back to `/usr/bin/`:

```
/etc/alternatives/vi -> /usr/bin/vim.gnome
/etc/alternatives/vim -> /usr/bin/vim.gnome
```

After wondering a bit why is it so, I came to the conclusion that both are pointing to the same executable, hence they are completely the same.

However, something cought my eye that moment; this link:

```
/etc/alternatives/view -> /usr/bin/vim.gnome
```

accompanied with this link:

```
/usr/bin/view -> /etc/alternatives/view
```

Now, that's weird, since I know that when I run `view` it's not the same as when I run `vim`; it opens a read-only mode of the file given as an argument. Does `vim.gnome` binary knows what was linking to it when executed, somehow?

(by the way, same issue is with `vimdiff`)

Do you have an explanation for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in `man vim`:

> Vim behaves differently, depending on the name of the command (the
>   executable may still be the same file).
>
> **vim:**    
>     The "normal" way, everything is default.
>
> **ex:**  
> Start  in Ex mode.  Go to Normal mode with the ":vi"
>   command.
>                Can also be done with the "-e" argument.
>
> **view:**      
> Start in read-only mode.  You will be protected from 
>   writing
>                the files.  Can also be done with the "-R" argument.
>
> **gvim gview:**
>                The GUI version.  Starts a new window.  Can also be done with
>                the "-g" argument.
>
> **evim eview:**
>                The GUI version in easy mode.  Starts a new window.  Can also
>                be done with the "-y" argument.
>
> **rvim rview rgvim rgview**
>                Like the above, but with restrictions.  It will not be possi‐
>                ble to start shell commands, or suspend  Vim.   Can  also  be
>                done with the "-Z" argument.

In other words, vim will detect the name it was invoked as and act accordingly. Another example of a program that behaves differently depending on which name it was run as is `bash` which acts as a minimal POSIX shell if called as `sh` (see INVOCATION in `man bash`).

Comment: This is great; but how vim knows the name of the command?

Comment: @Bach the name that a program is called by is available to that program. The details depend on the language used but, for example, in `bash` and `perl` you have `$0`. In C, which is what `vim` is written in, the name the executable was called by is stored in `argv[0]` and it is trivial to set up a few tests that make the program behave differently according to the value of `argv[0]`.